# Jetpack Compose – Which dependency do I need to use to be able to use state delegates?

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compile-time error with the samples provided in the code-labs.

This is the ViewModel

```kotlin
class VM : ViewModel() {
     val isVisible = MutableStateFlow(true).asStateFlow()
}
```

This is what I'd like to write:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Whatever(vm: VM = viewModel()) {
    val isVisible by vm.isVisible.collectAsState(true)
    // Use is visible here
}
```

But it yields to the following error:

> Type 'State<TypeVariable(R)>' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

Which is really strange because I can use it like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Whatever(vm: VM = viewModel()) {
    val isVisible = vm.isVisible.collectAsState(true)
    if(isVisible.value) { … }
}
```

What dependency do I need to bring in to make the delegate work?

Here are my dependencies: and `compose_version = 1.0.0-beta01`

```
dependencies {
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation-layout:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0'

    // Kotlin coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-beta02'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test:$compose_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#3), try to add the following imports:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
```

Comment: That is it. I've seen you answer another question with, _very likely_ import issues. Do you have any special config on Android Studio Preview that you could share?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy no special config, sorry